# Unable to work with gmp and uint64_t under windows in a sane manner

Tags: c++, windows, gmp, uint64

The following code works fine (compiles, assert statement gives true) under Linux/Debian (g++ 10.2), but refuses to work under Windows (mingw64 g++ 12.2.0). It's basically just supposed to assign `UINT64_MAX` to a `mpf_class` from the [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) library, but it seems gmp's `mpf_class` defines no constructor and no operators for `uint64_t`, which is unsigned long long int in the windows environment I'm trying to work with here. I bet there is a simple workaround I'm not seeing right now, because it's friday and late, correct?

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h> // link with gmp + gmpxx
#include <string>

/// Helper to convert mpf_class to std::string
[[nodiscard]] inline std::string mpf_class_to_str(const mpf_class& num) {
    mp_exp_t exponent(1);
    return num.get_str(exponent, 10);
}

int main() {
    mpf_class y = UINT64_MAX; // defined in my mingw64 as 0xffffffffffffffffULL
    //            ^
    //            |  adding no cast -> compile error
    //               adding (unsigned int) cast -> compiles, but assertion below false
    //               adding (uint64_t) cast -> compile error

    y *= UINT64_MAX; // UINT64_MAX²
    assert(mpf_class_to_str(y) == "340282366920938463426481119284349108225");
}
```

The compile error g++ gives me is:

```
error: conversion from 'long long unsigned int' to 'mpf_class' is ambiguous
   31 |             mpf_class y = UINT64_MAX;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

and then it lists all candidates, which basically are (taken from `gmpxx.h` instead of the error log):

```
#define __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS      \
  __gmp_expr(signed char c) { init_si(c); }     \
  __gmp_expr(unsigned char c) { init_ui(c); }       \
  __gmp_expr(signed int i) { init_si(i); }      \
  __gmp_expr(unsigned int i) { init_ui(i); }        \
  __gmp_expr(signed short int s) { init_si(s); }    \
  __gmp_expr(unsigned short int s) { init_ui(s); }  \
  __gmp_expr(signed long int l) { init_si(l); }     \
  __gmp_expr(unsigned long int l) { init_ui(l); }   \
  __gmp_expr(float f) { init_d(f); }            \
  __gmp_expr(double d) { init_d(d); }
```

If I manipulate that header adding the line `__gmp_expr(unsigned long long int l) { init_ui(l); }` all is well except this is too dirty of a fix even for me.

Comment: For now you have to decompose your uint64_t as x+y*(2**32) with uint32_t x and y, and then reconstruct the number from those.

Comment: what is the rest of the error when it tells you it's ambiguous? Or is that the whole error message?

Answer (score 3):

`mpz_class` cannot be constructed from a `(unsigned) long long`. That is also stated in the [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats#index-mpf_005fclass_003a_003ampf_005fclass).

The library does not support `(unsigned) long long`. See the mailing list thread [here](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2021-January/006622.html) (and several older ones). In the answer Marc Glisse also points out that this is mainly an issue on Windows.

He also suggested a patch for support of the C++ initialization/conversion part of the problem [here](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-devel/2022-April/006105.html), but I couldn't find it on gmp's public development repository yet. As he points out in the message, this would not cover arithmetic operations and such though.

Comment: So the only reason my example worked in linux world is because `unsigned long == unsigned long long` there 

Comment: @nada They are never the same type. If you tried to use `unsigned long long` on linux you would get the same result. However, it is more common to use types with explicit sizes and on linux (and most other platforms) the 64bit fixed-size types are `long` types, not `long long` ones. Windows decided to not make `long` 64bit though, so that doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying. With "==" I meant "are the same size", not the "same type", sorry for my sloppy wording there

Answer (score 1):

Besides patching the gmp library as suggested in [user17732522's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036967/4850111) it's also possible to get my example to work by using a conversion helper function. Something like this:

```cpp
/// Helper for converting anything to mpf_class.
namespace bigdec {
template<typename T> [[nodiscard]] inline
mpf_class get(const T& num) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    mpf_class bigdec;
    bigdec.set_str(ss.str(), 10);
    return bigdec;
}}
```

And changing the usage accordingly:

```cpp
int main() {
    mpf_class y = bigdec::get(UINT64_MAX); // <- here
    y *= bigdec::get(UINT64_MAX);          // <- and here
    assert(mpf_class_to_str(y) == "340282366920938463426481119284349108225");
}
```

Now it compiles and the assertion gives true in both - my Linux and Windows environment.